# No marketplace entries found to handle gmavenplus-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm getting an error message while trying to import an existing maven project into eclipse

"`No marketplace entries found to handle gmavenplus-plugin:1.6.1:addTestSources in eclipse`"

Any suggestions how can I get rid of this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Groovy-Eclipse](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse)? If so, version 5.0.0 has [a fix](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/commit/22608ca086906bab06c9409d2d8af4dca3ff9466) for GMavenPlus support that I believe should avoid this.